# Handle "dynamic Foreign Key columns" with Entity Framework Core and scaffolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

We have some tables in our database-design which include a column named "PK_ID". This columns are from type "uniqueidentifier" (Guid). The uniqueidentifier points to an entity in another table. So it is basically a Foreign Key column.

The special thing is that there is no constraint on this column. So you can put any uniqueidentifier - value in this column. We have an additional "Type"-column to determine to which table the uniqueidentifier is pointing to.

This certainly does not correspond to the good rules of database design, but it is necessary in our application context and that is not the point.

**Our poblem:**

When we scaffold our DbContext with `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` EF Core does not recognize the relationships to other tables via the "PK_ID" column. That is not surprising either.

But because this, we cannot use the "Include" and "IncludeThen" methods to build SQL-Join queries.

I hope that was somewhat understandable. How best to deal with this within EntityFramework Core? Is there a way to use methods like "Include" anyway?

Comment: Currently EF Core supports only physical enforced database relationships. What are you asking is called "polymorphic association" and is not supported, which means you cannot map it to navigation properties, hence you cannot use `Include`.

Comment: Thanks! "polymorphic association" was technical term i was searched for. Now i found much more on Google :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fluent syntax when querying for this so you can specify how to join

Syntax looks like this: Taken from here: https://entityframework.net/joining)

```
var data = context.Authors
    .Join(
        context.Books,
        author => author.AuthorId,
        book => book.Author.AuthorId,
        (author, book) => new
        {
            BookId = book.BookId,
            AuthorName = author.Name,
            BookTitle = book.Title
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for.